# Changing textbox border color when validation occurs with HappyJs

Tags: asp.net, css, validation, textbox

I'm trying to get the textbox border color to change when the validation kicks in on my form. I currently have a style set-up in the css:

```
input[type=text]:focus {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #0dc8e5;
}

input[type=text]:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #0dc8e5;
}
```

However, this needs to change to red if the `javascript` validation kicks in.

I'm using the following: [HappyJs](http://happyjs.com/).

Comment: What needs to change to red? How does the validation function look?

Comment: If you view the link provide; `STEP 2.` is how the function looks.

Comment: So do you want the text input to be red if the validation fails?

Comment: I think I understand your question, Ive added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With happy.js the "unhappy" class gets added if a fields validation changes.
So you can add the following to your CSS

```
.unhappy{
    border-color:red;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my class to add a border instead of a background color

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe it was something so simple. :D

Answer (score 0):

After an error occured you need to set a class for the specific input using jquery.

A quick example:

```
$("#register").validate({
                          debug: true,
                          errorClass:'error help-inline',
                          validClass:'success',
                          errorElement:'span',
                          highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
                            $(element).parents("div.control-group").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass); 

                          }, 
                          unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
                                  $(element).parents(".error").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass); 
                          },
```

Now you can style the class help-inline in your css with a red border/shadow.